# Gridview gaps appearing after icon added

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm getting an ugly gap in my gridview when I add an icon to it, what am I doing wrong?

```
gvTuteeListPG.Rows[rowCount].Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.Goldenrod;
gvTuteeListPG.Rows[rowCount].Cells[0].CssClass = "fa fa-exclamation-circle";
```

[image: screenshot of problem gaps]

Comment: Can you please try to apply the border to the grid view and try to identify what are that gap? you might get the solution.  once you apply the border, check the cell value by using browser developer toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You should not apply `fa fa-exclamation-circle` directly to table cell.

Instead, insert a ***span*** tag with class.

```
var span = new HtmlGenericControl();
span.Attributes["class"] = "fa fa-exclamation-circle";
gvTuteeListPG.Rows[rowCount].Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.Goldenrod;
gvTuteeListPG.Rows[rowCount].Cells[0].Controls.Add(span);
```